# Запятая между прилагательным и причастием

Tags: пунктуация, причастия

Нужна ли запятая и почему в следующей конструкции: "Некоторые из бывших советских республик(,) вступившие в организацию...", "Некоторые(,) вступившие..."? Благодарю.

Comment: Для решения задачи (постановки запятой и  выбора правильного падежа) нужно видеть предложение в полном объеме.

Comment: Разве республики (не по одиночке) могут быть единственными?

Comment: зачем вы заменили на слово некоторые? Единственные вступившие - единственные из какого-то числа, меня интересует конструкция. Пусть будет единственная вступившая - это фигура речи, так говорят и меня интересует пунктуация.

Comment: Узбекистан и Беларусь - единственные из бывших советских республик, вступившие (подписавшие и т.д.) Как видите, ваша правка неуместна, и не следовало ее вносить.

Comment: Sergey, вот пример более полного предложения. "Узбекистан и Беларусь - единственные из бывших советских республик(,) вступившие (подписавшие)... Вот эта конструкция тоже интересует "единственная предложившая свои услуги организация". Буду благодарна за ответ и разъяснение

Comment: "Разве республики (не по одиночке) могут быть единственными?" Конечно, могут. Тоже не понимаю правки, зачем искажать! Каждая республика единственн**ая,** а несколько (а тем более две) единственн**ые.**

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна: "Некоторые из бывших советских республик, вступившие в организацию".

Comment: Здравствуйте, Настасья. Спасибо за отклик. Там изначально было "единственные вступившие" - "Единственные из республик(,)вступившие". Почему здесь нужна запятая?